# Is there a way to see the codes inside nugets?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio

This says that nugets are codes other programmers have done for us.

I download a lot of nugets. Notably newtonsoft json and nethereum.

However, I can never see the code inside the objects I use.

For example,

[Why I cannot send ftm with this simple code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616326/why-i-cannot-send-ftm-with-this-simple-code)

The nethereum nugget thrown an exception. The most likely cause is I am using fantom blockchain that doesn't support some new ethereum feature.

However, I cannot step into nethereum codes and see that.

I wonder if I actually can do that.

Nethereum is open source.

Are all nugets open source?

In visual studio.

I can right click and go to definition. However I cannot see the implementation.

For example

Nethereum.RPC will look like this

```
#region Assembly Nethereum.RPC, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8768a594786aba4e
// C:\Users\teguh\.nuget\packages\nethereum.rpc\4.5.0\lib\net5.0\Nethereum.RPC.dll
// Decompiled with ICSharpCode.Decompiler 7.1.0.6543
#endregion

using System.Collections.Generic;
using Nethereum.Hex.HexTypes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Nethereum.RPC.Eth.DTOs
{
    public class TransactionInput : CallInput
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "nonce")]
        public HexBigInteger Nonce { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "accessList")]
        public List<AccessList> AccessList { get; set; }

        public TransactionInput()
        {
        }

        public TransactionInput(string data, string addressTo)
            : base(data, addressTo)
        {
        }

        public TransactionInput(string data, string addressTo, HexBigInteger value)
            : base(data, addressTo, value)
        {
        }

        public TransactionInput(string data, string addressTo, string addressFrom, HexBigInteger gas, HexBigInteger value)
            : base(data, addressTo, addressFrom, gas, value)
        {
        }

        public TransactionInput(string data, string addressFrom, HexBigInteger gas, HexBigInteger value)
            : base(data, addressFrom, gas, value)
        {
        }

        public TransactionInput(string data, string addressTo, string addressFrom, HexBigInteger gas, HexBigInteger gasPrice, HexBigInteger value)
            : base(data, addressTo, addressFrom, gas, gasPrice, value)
        {
        }

        public TransactionInput(string data, HexBigInteger gas, string addressFrom)
            : base(data, gas, addressFrom)
        {
        }

        public TransactionInput(HexBigInteger type, string data, string addressTo, string addressFrom, HexBigInteger gas, HexBigInteger value, HexBigInteger maxFeePerGas, HexBigInteger maxPriorityFeePerGas)
            : base(data, addressTo, addressFrom, gas, value, type, maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas)
        {
        }
    }
}
#if false // Decompilation log
```

Just the interface. No implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dnSpy to look inside the .dll which is located in the output directory after build.

https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy

Comment: How exactly I use it? Install the 64 version? Which one? Download here? https://github.com/dnSpy/dnSpy/releases

Comment: yes, download dnSpy-net-win64.zip or dnSpy-net-win32.zip if you are using a 32bit System.